# Place to publish file format specifications?

Tags: xml, publishing

Is there a central place where file format specifications (specifically XML-based formats) are published?  We have created an XML-based spec for storing a particular type of data from an instrument.  Of course we will publish our spec in the places relevant to potential users, but is there a place (like WC3 for example) that hosts the specs for a variety of file types, in effect allowing us to submit the file type and make it 'official/published' with a pervasive, permanent presence?  What I mean by specifications is something like the man pages for what constitutes a compliant file format.

If it is relevant, we also have associated stylesheets and APIs in Python and C++.

Comment: It sounds as if you've developed your own file specification, which is not the same as a standard. A standard is something that is accepted across an entire industry, and typically is approved by a committee of representatives from the major players within that industry. A specification is an agreement between entities that they will adhere to a specified format when communicating between each other.

Comment: That is absolutely correct; I have been using the improper word. The community in question has tried to get together to make standards but there has never been adequate consensus.  I will modify the question (thank you for pointing out the difference).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a central place where file format specifications (specifically XML-based formats) are published?

No, there is not. Unless you count "the web" as a central place. The web is decentralized by design.

This is why the convention exists to use DNS names in namespace URIs; it allows the repository of vocabularies to be distributed and decentralized.